# Create edges in Blender

Tags: 3d, models, 3d-meshes, blender, 3dsmax

I've worked with 3DS Max in Uni and am trying to learn Blender.

My problem is I know a lot of simple techniques from 3DS max that I'm having trouble translating into Blender. So my question is:

Say I have a poly in the middle of a mesh and I want to split it in two. Simply adding an edge between two edges. This would cause a two 5gons either side.

It's a simple technique I use every now and then when I want to modify geometry. It's called "Edge connect" in 3DS Max.

In Blender the only edge connect method I can find is to create edge loops, not helpful when aiming at low poly iPhone games.

Is there an equivalent in blender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily, Blender's BMesh support is finally here, as of 2.63. You're looking for the "Knife" tool. See http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh

hit `K` in edit-mode to switch to the knife, and click to set up points to "cut". Spacebar exits knife mode.

[image]

Comment: Yep the knife tool is perfect. Specifically Shift+k seems to do knife at edge midpoints, which combined with edge slide is the exact functionality of edge connect. Thanks.